# What is difference between these two cookie configurations for cookie-based authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity, identity

What is difference between these two cookie configurations for cookie-based authentication?

### Variant 1

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    // Configure cookie based authentication:
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(opt =>
            {
                /* validation rules */    
            });
}
```

### Variant 2

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(opt =>
    {
        /* validation rules */
    });

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/User/Login");

        options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
        {
            Name = "AspNetCoreIdentityExampleCookie",
            HttpOnly = false,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
            SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
        };

        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
}
```

---

I can't understand the difference, I will be glad for hearing any help.

Comment: Variant 1 is the manual way to configure cookie-based auth without using the provided Indtity framework, whereas variant 2, calling AddIdentity, automatically adds the cookie-based auth, and you can fine-tune the configurations by using ConfigureApplicationCookie. more details on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-7.0,

Comment: @CharlesHan thanks, for answer, if u can add your this answer as a Answer to this question, not here like comment and then i can check your answer as a 'Accepted answer'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variant one involves configuring cookie-based authentication manually, without utilizing the provided Identity framework. On the other hand, Variant two involves calling `AddIdentity`, which automatically adds cookie-based authentication and allows for customization of the configuration using `ConfigureApplicationCookie`.

[Reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: +1. Just out of interest, why is `ConfigureApplicationCookie` not part of the Identity namespace when it (*appears*) to be only used within that context?  Is it because that cookie configuration can apply to additional auth middleware?